# $p(x) \in T[x]$. For $\alpha \in T$ to be a multiple root of $p(x)$, a necessary and sufficient condition is that $p(\alpha)=0$ and $p'(\alpha)=0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $T$ be a zone of completeness and $p(x) \in T[x]$. For $\alpha \in T$ to be a multiple root of $p(x)$, a necessary and sufficient condition is that $p(\alpha)=0$ and $p'(\alpha)=0$. Show me. I tried a lot but I don't know how to do it please help.

Comment: What do you mean by a "domain of completeness"

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  We ask that you explain what you did and where you are stuck in more detail, so that we can help more.

Comment: It's zone of completeness

Comment: @Noah Solomon: I'm pretty sure means "integral domain".

Comment: Yeah I guess you're right

Answer (score 1):

If $\alpha$ is a root of $p(x)$ then $(x-\alpha)$ divides $p(x)$. That is $p(x) = (x-\alpha)q(x)$ for some polynomial $q(x)$. If $\alpha$ is a multiple root then it must also be a root of $q(x)$ (and if $\alpha$ is a root of $q(x)$ then it is a multiple root of $p(x)$).

Then $p'(x) = (x-a)q'(x) + q(x)$. It follows that $p'(\alpha) = 0 \iff q(\alpha) = 0$.

Comment: Thank you. Are you sure about the solution?